# Pandas get list of columns if columns name contains

Tags: pandas

I have written this code to show a list of column names in a dataframe if they contains 'a','b' ,'c' or 'd'.

I then want to say trim the first 3 character of the column name for these columns.

However its showing an error. Is there something wrong with the code?

```
ind_cols= [x for x in df if df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(['a','b','c','d']))]]

df[ind_cols].columns=df[ind_cols].columns.str[3:]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `if-else`:

```
L = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(['a','b','c','d']))]
df.columns = [x[3:] if x in L else x for x in df.columns]
```

Another solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) by boolean mask:

```
m = df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(['a','b','c','d']))
df.columns = np.where(m, df.columns.str[3:], df.columns)
```